# @NX/Angular App works on other browser, but not on safari

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, nx-angular

I have an @nx/angular app that works perfectly on Chrome browser. However, it doesn't work on safari browser. No error is dumped on the Javascript Console. the closest thing to an error that is dropped is as follows.

```
NG0912: Component ID generation collision detected. Components 'CdkVirtualScrollViewport' and 'CdkVirtualScrollViewport' with selector 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' generated the same component ID. To fix this, you can change the selector of one of those components or add an extra host attribute to force a different ID. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0912
```

This is dumped despite the fact that there's no apparent use of the component `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` in the project. I've tried to isolate parts of the app, yet no luck. I will appreciate a pointer to how I can troubleshoot this issue.

I just need the app to work on Safari.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? Dealing with same issue.

Comment: This wasn't the issue. I had a library I was using it's id to import classes within the same library. There was some form of circular dependency. My grouse is just that there was no error logged for it.